# SQL abstractions

Tags: sql, database, orm

Why do some frameworks (like CakePHP, Kohana, Zend, Django, less - Rails) create some kind of SQL abstractions instead of a raw SQL database access? E.g. why do we need to make some perversions instead of a usual queries?

**UPD:** are there any SQL-injection reasons of this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically a good abstraction layer makes it easier for the developer to use a database, and not care what what and which kind of database he is connecting to, thus speeding up the development process.

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer, the most common pros and cons are listed here.

Comment: I don't think we'll be writing scalable applications without caring about the underlying database anytime soon.

Comment: Hehe, true, but the question was about the purpose of abstraction layers regarding databases. If you're building something scalable, you ofc have to care about the database. But for a common local application without the need of heavy load performance it usually doesn't matter very much if you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server or whatever. In those case other aspects are more important (p.e. licencing) and a good abstraction layer simplifies adapting it.

Answer (score 0):

Thats called abstraction. Usually its done to be db specific indipendent. 
Sql will be built based on the db type of the connection..

Answer (score 0):

There are two main reasons.

- Database Indepence

The code can be applied to different databases. MySQL, MS SQL-SERVER, ORACLE. And with a little wrangling to other DBs using OBDC like MSAccess, or CSV files.

- Separation of Database Code with Business Logic

Most frameworks follow this model: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Answer (score 0):

It's primarily an attempt to reduce what's known as the impedance mismatch between the relational storage of the database and the domain model within your application.  Without the ORM you often find yourself writing "left hand right hand" code `modelobject.property = reader["field]`  where you're mapping values from the storage format you've received from the database into your model.

In summary, hopefully the ORM allows you to concentrate on solving the business problems without having to worry about all of the plumbing.  We're not there yet but we're getting close.